# Problem with understanding a cross product related problem

Tags: cross-product

I have a question that follows like this:

> Let $U = (0,1,2)$ and $V = (1,-1,-2)$. Assume that $V \times W = (3,1,1)$
>
> Is there enough information provided in order to determine $(U \times V) \times W$ and $W \times (V \times W)$?

According to the answer sheet, there is no enough information to determine the mentioned cross products according to the question. But I do not know how to explain this algebraically nor geometrically.

Comment: As far as I know, the Cross Product follows the Right hand rule to determine a perpendicular vector on two given vectors. Now if the perpendicular vector is already given and one of the two other vectors is given, then we have options for the missing vector i.e. try the right hand rule out for yourself. These images may help you...https://www.google.com/search?q=right+hand+rule+cross+product&newwindow=1&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=XTv6VLfkLMS6ggSj0YNY&ved=0CB4QsAQ&biw=1024&bih=452

Comment: Basically any vector which forms a parallelogram (of one specific orientation) of area $\sqrt{11}$ with the vector $V$ and is in the plane orthogonal to $(3,1,1)$ will work.  So basically, given $V\times W = (3,1,1)$ and $V$ you can narrow down what $W$ is to a semicircle of vectors.  But without knowing exactly what $W$ is, you can't calculate either of those triple products.

Comment: I know about the right hand rule and tried to convince myself about the answer on the given question by using the right hand rule, but I still cannot convince myself about the answer on the right question. How shall I then apply this rule in order to motivate myself that the cross products cannot be calculated?

Comment: As long as you can tell that you can't calculate exactly what direction that $W$ points in (you can calculate it's length and figure out a half-plane that it lies in, but that's not enough in this case), you should be able to see that you can't figure out which direction $W \times (V \times W)$ points in, and thus you can't calculate it.  The same is true of the other triple product.

Comment: @Bye_World, so you mean that the simple reason is that we do not know the vector W in order to determine these cross products? Is it just only that? Could this be extended in form of algebraic calculations in order to verify that those cross products cannot be calculated or something like that?

Comment: You can't do the algebra without knowing $W$.  You can't do it geometrically either because there is no way of specifying the exact direction that $W$ points in.  I don't see any calculation that you would need to prove that.  I suggest you just argue your case (as I did, but you can flesh out the details yourself) geometrically.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Let me summarize for myself: the reason that those cross products cannot be calculated is because it is unknown about what direction the vector W points at on a three-dimensional plane? Have I wrong or something I have missed in my summary of the reasoning?

Comment: What is a $3$-dimensional plane?  Planes are $2$-dimensional (maybe you mean hyperplane?).  You can narrow down the direction of $W$ to a half plane in $\Bbb R^3$, but that's not good enough to determine which direction the cross product of $W$ and another vector is in.

Comment: Sorry for my terminology! Yes, is is hyperplane that is ment because you have plane in which the vectors can point right or left and also point upwards as well downwards if you understand what I try to describe.

So the problem with calculating the mentioned cross products is that we just don't now where the W arrows on that half plane in R^3?

Comment: Right.  And if we don't know where $W$ points, we won't know where $W \times A$ points (unless $A$ happens to be on the same plane as we've narrowed $W$ down to -- which $V \times W$ definitely isn't and I'm going to guess $U\times V$ isn't either -- but even if it were, we still wouldn't know the angle between the two).

Comment: I now believe that the geometric picture has been clarified for my about this mathematical problem. Thanks for your time effort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an algebraic way to see this:

Setting $\vec{w}=\langle w_1,w_2,w_3\rangle$, $\vec{v}\times\vec{w}=\langle2w_2-w_3,-2w_1-w_3,w_1+w_2\rangle=\langle3,1,1\rangle$, so

solving the system $2w_2-w_3=3, \;\;2w_1+w_3=-1,\;\;w_1+w_2=1$ gives

$\;\;\;\vec{w}=\langle\frac{1}{2}-t,\; \frac{3}{2}+t,\; 2t\rangle$.

In particular, taking $t=\frac{1}{2}\;$ gives $\vec{w}=\langle -1,2,1\rangle$, and taking $t=-\frac{1}{2}\;$ gives $\vec{w}=\langle0,1,-1\rangle$.

Now it is easy to show that these values of $\vec{w}$ give different values for

$(\vec{u}\times\vec{v})\times\vec{w}=\langle0,2,-1\rangle\times\vec{w}$, and for $\vec{w}\times(\vec{v}\times\vec{w})=\vec{w}\times\langle3,1,1\rangle$.

Comment: Wow, that was very clearly explained. Thanks for the algebraic calculations!

Comment: Thanks for your positive comments!